# How to use oracle from grails

Tags: oracle, grails

this is my DataSource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
    username = "peter"
    password = "wuffwuff"
}

environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.128:1521:XE"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.128:1521:XE"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.128:1521:XE"
        }
    }
}
```

this is what I get on application start prod:

```
Running Grails application

| Error 2014-12-21 11:12:32,287 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.

Message: E/A-Exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

.......

ping of 192.168.2.128 is working fine

Comment: Having the host _reachable_ does not necessarily mean that (1) the Oracle listener is running on it (2) it is listening at port 1521 (3) there isn't some firewall blocking that traffic. Maybe you should issue a `tnsping 192.168.2.128:1521/xe`.

Comment: You can also use the `sqlplus` command that's in the bundle of the XE edition.

Comment: A university that uses Banner, I presume? ;)

Comment: peter@koala:~$ tnsping 192.168.2.128:1521/xe
tnsping: Befehl nicht gefunden. (=command not found)

Comment: last night I succeeded in accessing the database on localhost, after installing my application on the same system where oracle xe is running.

Comment: could it be that I face a XE restriction, that xe is not accessible from outside the computer, where oracle xe is running. all over the internet I only found localhost examples.