# how to code the Url for oracle database in grails dataSource.config

Tags: oracle, grails

I'm trying to connect from grails to oracle 10gXE.
All over the net I only find a Url for localhost:
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
But I need to connect to a host in my local network
I can ping it successfully with ping 192.168.2.128

but
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.128:1521:XE"
ends up with:

```
Error 2014-12-22 14:26:23,612 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool. 
Message: E/A-Exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection   
 Line | Method


->>  112 | throwSqlException in oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError
|    146 | throwSqlException in     ''
|    255 | throwSqlException in     ''
|    387 | logon             in oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection
|    414 | <init> . . . . .  in oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection
|    165 | <init>            in oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection
|     35 | getConnection . . in oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension    
|    801 | connect           in oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver    
|    262 | run . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask    
|   1145 | runWorker         in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor    
|    615 | run . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker   
^    745 | run               in java.lang.Thread
```

peter
Dortmund Germany

ps.
my complete Data source:

```
dataSource {
pooled = true
driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
username = "peter"
password = "wuffwuff"
```

}

```
environments {
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.128:1521:XE"
    }
}
test {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.128:1521:XE"
    }
}
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.128:1521:XE"
        username = "peter"
        password = "wuffwuff"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use oracle from grails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588562/how-to-use-oracle-from-grails)

Comment: There are already some suggestions in your [preceding question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588562/how-to-use-oracle-from-grails). Have you tried them ? What is the outcome ? It is [usually considered a bad thing to ask again a question that hasn't been answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/473/can-i-re-ask-a-question-if-it-hasnt-been-answered).